# What are the uses of Brainfuck?

Tags: brainfuck

Are there any confirmed (Documented by the creators, etc) uses or features of Brainfuck that are specific to itself?

Comment: There are no practical uses for that language. The only reason it exists is just "for fun"

Comment: I'd assumed this already, but I was told that a 'language shouldn't be put down for being 'hard to read', there are other reasons to make one'.

Comment: If you're going to accept an answer that begins with IMO maybe you should remove the disclaimer that says not to answer with opinions...

Comment: Regardless of the request for facts, this is far too off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BoltClock Apparently, I am an internet scrub; I had no idea what 'IMO' meant ;)

Comment: @200_success What I should have put, is 'over other, higher-level, languages' ;)

Comment: You could probably use brainfuck for code obfuscation

Comment: Nowadays, there are some people who might say "I don't like/want programming language X; it's too easy/simple", then the perfect reply would be "then build applications using Brainfuck" :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no practical uses of Brainfuck.

Comment: Wikipedia agrees: "It is a Turing tarpit, designed to challenge and amuse programmers, and was not made to be suitable for practical use."

Comment: @Dmitri: With that reasoning, no language is "practical". You don't need any of the existing languages. Yet some are practical to do certain tasks.

Answer (score 22):

IMO, the goals of the Brainfuck language are

- To demonstrate what a practical language should NOT look like;
- To demonstrate that even a poorly-designed language can be Turing-complete;
- To brag in front of your programmer friends, e.g. "I've written a calculator in Brainfuck!"
- To "f*ck (~= train) your brains" and getting practice. Just like a puzzle. There are also no very practical uses of the Rubik's cube, right?

Comment: The question says "Please keep opinions *far* away from this Q, so facts only please.", yet your answer begins with "IMO".

Comment: I knew I would get such a comment :) That's fair. But if I'd omit the "IMO", these statements would not become facts. They are still just my opinion. "No practical uses" is also just an opinion. This question is a request for opinions in its nature.

Comment: Still a pretty good answer to this question. While the accepted answer just drops a "no", this answer explains why it exists.